# Smart GWT Calendar: How to customize appearance of Events and Calendar itself?

Tags: javascript, calendar, customization, smartgwt

I would like to customize my smart GWT Calendar. Is this possible?

For example:

- Have something written between Calendar and Day-/Weeks-Tabs.
- Have some horizontal space between the Events.
- Change the appearance of the events: If there are three events a day, each event should just have a third of the horizontal space.

What to do?

- Do I have to change any JavaScript Files? If yes, how. Which are the crucial files?
- What's about the .setProperty(property, value) Methods? There is no documentation.